# Mongo Db .skip() Return values

Tags: mongodb, theory

Hi A quick theoretical question,

When mongodb returns the set after using a command like

```
db.collection.find().skip(1000)
```

Does it just return from the 1000th object to the end of the collection or does it return every object in the collection but begins at the 1000th object, similar to a circular queue.

The only reason I am asking is because after I ran the following commands on my database I got these results.

```
>>db.mycollection.find().skip(33405000).count()
>>393245869
>>db.mycollection.find().count()
>>393245869
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now your question is more interesting. 
From official MongoDB documentation you can read:

> By default, the count() method ignores the effects of the
>   cursor.skip() and cursor.limit(). Set applySkipLimit to true to
>   consider the effect of these methods.

Try this:

```
db.collection.find().skip(33405000).count({applySkipLimit:true})
```

For more info you can see [cursor.count](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.count/)